# Attempting to parse a file into an array but get extra digits

Tags: c, arrays, string, parsing, strtok

I have a text file full of data in this format (It's the output from a 3D graphic editor  .vox format)...

```
6 -13 8 eeeeec
13 -13 8 eeeeec
6 -12 8 eeeeec
6 -11 8 eeeeec
6 -10 8 eeeeec
1 -9 8 eeeeec
2 -9 8 eeeeec
3 -9 8 eeeeec
```

and I am using the following code to parse the integers into an array...

```
#include<stdio.h>

int array[10000];
char *p;

    int main()
    {
            FILE *ptr_file;
            char buf[10];

            ptr_file =fopen("AntAttackMap.txt","r");
            if (!ptr_file)
                return 1;

            long index = 0;

            while (fgets(buf,10, ptr_file)!=NULL)
            {
                p = strtok(buf, " ec");

              while (p != NULL)
              {

                int num = atoi(p);
                array[index]=num;
                printf ("%d ",num);
                p = strtok (NULL, " ec");
                if (p != NULL) index++;
              }
            }

        fclose(ptr_file);
         printf("TOTAL %d, ",index);
            return 0;
    }
```

However, the output has extra zero's in-between the 3 digits as follows:

```
6 -13 8 0 13 -13 8 0 6 -12 8 0 6 -11 8 0 6 -10 8 0 1 -9 8 0 2 -9 8 0 3 -9 8 0
```

Can somebody please explain why I am getting the extra digits please?

Thanks in advance,

Mike

Comment: `" ec"` --> `" ec\n"`

Comment: Your buffer size of  `10` is not big enough to hold `13 -13 8 eeeeec`.  Use a sensible size — maybe 4096, or perhaps just 1024, or 256.

Comment: Thanks BLUEPIXY that was what the problem was.

Comment: Jonathon thanks. It was still doing it incorrectly with a larger buffer. I forget to parse for the newline.

Answer (score 0):

You can use BUFSIZ constant,
Example

```
char buf[BUFSIZ];
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `atoi` for parsing integers. The only reliable way is `strtoul`. Then, add error checking to the code, and you should be fine.